# Cannot Change Language on Api 18

Tags: android, locale

i have android application and i tried to change language in the app , its working good on android +20 api ,,, but on api 18 its not working ! 
this is my code please help me !

```
    private void changeLanguage() {
        if (getCurrentLanguage(context) == "en") {
            Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            onConfigurationChanged(config);
            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("Language", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
            prefEditor.putString("locale_override", "ar");
            prefEditor.commit();
        } else {
//
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            onConfigurationChanged(config);
            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("Language", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
            prefEditor.putString("locale_override", "en");
            prefEditor.commit();
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you restart current activity with new language set by calling **changeLanguage()**. If it is so, firstly I suggest you add a few lines of code at the end of **changeLanguage()**:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
i.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // start the activity in new task
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // finish the current activity
```

And in SplashScreen **onCreate()** add:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Language", MODE_PRIVATE);
String lang = settings.getString("locale_override","en"); // "en" is the default if there is no previously set language
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

This way, when you restart the activity, Locale will be set according to the language setting. When you start the activity for the fist time, language will be **en**, since it is set as default for lang string. You can of course change the default to **ar** if you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for replay , but its not working on  Android 4.3 (JELLY_BEAN_MR2)

Comment: It definetly works from api level 15 up. I'm using it myself to change languages in one of my apps. If you like I can send you the complete sample code.